# Why project 3d to 2d out of image plane while the point lies on the image

Tags: perspectivecamera

I am trying to get the 2D coordinate on image plane given the 3D world coordinate in Unreal engine 4.

The world coordinate system is **x**(increase from right to left), **y**(increase from outside to inside screen), **z**(increase from bottom to top)

The image coordinate system I want is origin on bottom left and **x**(increase from left to right), **y**(increase from bottom to top)

I set up my camera intrinsic and extrinsic as below while the camera is located on

```
(-474.9739990234375, -67.140998840332031, 128.10400390625)
```

and its rotation is

```
(0, 0.80071002244949341, 99.797645568847656)
```

related to the origin of world coordinate.

```py
import numpy as np

fov = 69.4
width = 1920.0
height = 1080.0
aspect_ratio = width / height
fx = width / (2 * np.tan(fov * np.pi / 2 / 180))
fy = height / (2 * np.tan(fov / aspect_ratio / 2 / 180 * np.pi))
intrinsic = [[-fx, 0, width / 2], [0, fy, height / 2], [0 , 0, 1]]

pitch = 0.80071002244949341 * np.pi / 180
yaw = 99.797645568847656 * np.pi / 180
roll = 0 * np.pi / 180

ry = [[np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)], [0, 1, 0], [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]]
rx = [[1, 0, 0], [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)], [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]]
rz = [[np.cos(yaw), -np.sin(yaw), 0], [np.sin(yaw), np.cos(yaw), 0], [0, 0, 1]]
rotation_matrix = np.matmul(np.matmul(rx, ry), rz)

translation_matrix = np.array([[-474.9739990234375, -67.140998840332031, 128.10400390625]])

extrinsic = np.concatenate([rotation_matrix, translation_matrix.T], axis=1)
extrinsic = np.concatenate([extrinsic, np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]])], axis=0)
extrinsic = np.linalg.inv(extrinsic)
extrinsic = extrinsic[:3]
print(extrinsic)
```

Let's say I have an object in the scene which are also in the camera view.
Its coordinate is

```py
[-582.88897705078125, 143.63600158691406, 88.338996887207031]
```

Using the code below I should get the projection of the 3D point on image plane.

```py
world_coordinate = np.array([[-582.88897705078125, 143.63600158691406, 88.338996887207031, 1]])
camera_coordinate = np.dot(extrinsic, world_coordinate.T)
print(camera_coordinate)
camera_coordinate[0] *= 1
tmp = camera_coordinate[1].copy()
camera_coordinate[1] = camera_coordinate[2]
camera_coordinate[2] = tmp
print(camera_coordinate)
image_coordinate = np.dot(intrinsic, camera_coordinate)
image_coordinate /= image_coordinate[2]
print(image_coordinate)
```

But I got

```
[[-3.52097326e+03]
 [-3.59180874e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00]]
```

Which does not lie on image plane. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a mistake. The actual world coordinate system is **x**(increase from outside to inside screen), **y**(increase from left to right), **z**(increase from bottom to top).

Just map the project the yz plane to image space then it'll be done.